# How to convert json into dictionary for POST api call Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

How to convert json into dictionary for POST api call Swift

Answer (score 3):

`info` contains an array of object that have `User` and `Address` keys  You need

```
let dict1 : [String:Any] = ["ID" : "User123", "Name" : "Virat", "UserID" : 0] 
let dict2 : [String:Any] = ["city" : "Delhi", "pin" : 123]
let addressDict : [String:Any] = ["User" : dict1,"Address" : dict2] 
let infoDict : [String:Any] = ["info" :[addressDict]]
```

To better understand look to

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct Empty: Codable {
    let info: [Info]
}

// MARK: - Info
struct Info: Codable {
    let user: User
    let address: Address

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user = "User"
        case address = "Address"
    }
}

// MARK: - Address
struct Address: Codable {
    let city: String
    let pin: Int
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let id, name: String
    let userID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case userID = "UserID"
    }
}
```

You can also use the models above and convert the model to `Data` with `JSONEncodable`

Comment: Perfect One @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're adding user and address as separate dictionaries on the array.

The JSON you posted has an array for `info` key but its ONE dictionary with two keys.

You need to combine the address and user dicts into one declaration and then wrap that in an array.

For ex:

```
let dict1 : [String:Any] = ["ID" : "User123", "Name" : "Virat", "UserID" : 0]
let dict2 : [String:Any] = ["city" : "Delhi", "pin" : 123]
let dicts : [String:Any] = ["User": dict1, "Address" : dict2]
let arr = [dicts]
let infoDict : [String:Any] = ["info" : arr]
```

EDIT: I would agree with SH_Khan that a much better way of doing this would be to create a Codable model

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are make dictionary per object.

try this code:

```
let userDict : [String:Any] = ["ID" : "User123", "Name" : "Virat", "UserID" : 0]
let addressDict : [String:Any] = ["city" : "Delhi", "pin" : 123]
let infoDict : [String:Any] = ["info" : ["User": addressDict, "Address": addressDict]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func getDictionaryFromString(_ json: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    let json = """
                {"info": [{
                          "User": {"ID": "user123",
                                   "Name": "Virat",
                                   "UserID": 0
                                  },
                          "Address": {"city": "Delhi",
                                    "pin": 123
                                     }
                          }
                        ]
                }
                """

    if let dict = getDictionaryFromString(json) {
        print(dict["info"] as! NSArray)
    }


}
```

//Printed:

```
> (
>         {
>         Address =         {
>             city = Delhi;
>             pin = 123;
>         };
>         User =         {
>             ID = user123;
>             Name = Virat;
>             UserID = 0;
>         };
>     } )
```